# How to download a dynamically generated file from server to client from a webpart?

Tags: 2013, web-part, download

I have a webpart that needs to create dynamically a `.zip` file in the server and download that file to the client machine, once the user clicks on an Export button.

The `.zip` generation is ready, I just need to know how to download the file to the client machine, in a way the user chooses the destination directory. I saw 2 main different solutions over the internet: one uses the `Response.TransmitFile/WriteFile`, and the other one involves creating a download page. Is there a easiest way to do this directly from the code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the `MemoryStream`, the below code will bring the `Save Dialog` so user can choose the path

```
Byte[] byteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
memoryStream.Flush();
memoryStream.Close();
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=filename.zip");
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
Response.End();
```

**Fix for non-responsive events**

Change your Export button as follows

```
<asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export" OnClick="Export_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:setFormSubmitToFalse()" />
```

Add this JavaScript function to the ASCX file

```
function setFormSubmitToFalse() {
    setTimeout(function () { _spFormOnSubmitCalled = false; }, 1000);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amal, but as I explained to Naim, I tried this solution before, and it freezes the webpart after the Response.End(), it only works once, so it's not acceptable for the web part.

Comment: @tcbrazil please try my fix.

Comment: Amal, it worked! I found an excellent explanation [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749393/no-more-post-back-after-file-download-in-sharepoint) here on why we need to add this JavaScript function.

The solution based on an exclusive download page worked as well, but as a good cartesian-minded guy, I don't like it for adding an "unnecessary" component.

Answer (score 0):

In the event handler of your Export button use this code

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=YourFile.zip");
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes); //bytes is byte[] of your zip file
Response.End();
```

Comment: Thanks Naim, but this is one of the solutions I tried, and it freezes the webpart after the Response.End(), it only works once, so it's not acceptable for the webpart.

Comment: I use this in application pages with no issues. As you have tested it doesn't work in web parts. Let's wait for other users ideas.

Comment: If you don't find better solution one workaround is to have one application page just for that purpose. That page doesn't have to be shown to the users. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025609/response-writefile-in-sharepoint-webpart)